# How does a cmdlet know when it really should call WriteVerbose()?

Tags: powershell

How does a cmdlet know when it *really* should call `WriteVerbose()`,
`WriteDebug()` and etc.?

Perhaps I miss something simple but I cannot find the answer. All cmdlet
implementations I have seen so far just call `WriteVerbose()` without any
hesitation. I know that it is *correct* to do so, but it is not *effective*.

Performance suffers when verbose mode is off but a cmdlet still prepares
data for `WriteVerbose()` call, that is, for nothing.

In other words, in a cmdlet I would like to be able to:

```
if (<VerboseMode>)
{
    .... data preparation, sometimes expensive ...
    WriteVerbose(...);
}
```

But I don't know how to get this `if (<VerboseMode>)`. Any ideas?

---

**Conclusion:**
The @stej’s answer shows how get the required information in theory. In practice this is hacky and unlikely suitable. Thus, if a cmdlet produces really expensive verbose or debug output then it looks reasonable to introduce an additional parameter specifying verbosity levels.

Comment: I don't agree with your conclusion. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is method from `System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime`.

```
internal void WriteVerbose(VerboseRecord record)
{
    if ((this.Host == null) || (this.Host.UI == null))
    {
        tracer.TraceError("No host in CommandBase.WriteVerbose()", new object[0]);
        throw tracer.NewInvalidOperationException();
    }
    ActionPreference verbosePreference = this.VerbosePreference;
    if (this.WriteHelper_ShouldWrite(verbosePreference, this.lastVerboseContinueStatus))
    {
        if (record.InvocationInfo == null)
        {
            record.SetInvocationInfo(this.MyInvocation);
        }
        this.CBhost.InternalUI.WriteVerboseRecord(record);
    }
    this.lastVerboseContinueStatus = this.WriteHelper(null, null, verbosePreference, this.lastVerboseContinueStatus, "VerbosePreference");
}
```

`MshCommandRuntime` implements interface `ICommandRuntime` which doesn't know anything about verbosity :| (found through reflector). Instance of `MshCommandRuntime` should be available in `Cmdlet` (`public ICommandRuntime CommandRuntime { get; set; }`).

So it should be possible to cast property `CommandRuntime` to `MshCommandRuntime` and check the verbosity. Anyway, this is really ugly.

---

I totally agree that there should be an easy way how to find it out. And besides that (dreaming) compiler should be clever enough not to evaluate some strings in cases like this:

```
$DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$array = 1..1000
Write-Debug "my array is $array"
```

Input to `Write-Debug` will be never used, so `$array` shouldn't be evaluated in passed string.. (it is possible to test that it is really evaluated like this: `Write-Debug "my array is $($array|%{write-host $_; $_})"`

Comment: @stej: Thank you for your useful investigation. Theoretically it should be possible to hack in this way using reflection (because most of stuff is internal and not accessible normally). But of course this is not a practical solution. Nevertheless, I will accept the answer in a while if we do not find better alternatives.

I also found a related suggestion at Connect:
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/74811/performance-provide-formatting-overloads-for-writeverbose-writedebug-etc 
(This will not be enough though, I think; we need a flag IsVerbose, IsDebug, etc.)

Comment: @Roman, voted. | What currently came to my mind - when developing cmdlet, you should have access to all variables, shouldn't you. Then it is be possible to get `$DebugPrecedence` and act accordingly. Not ideal, but should work.

Comment: `$DebugPreference`, `$VerbosePreference` are better than nothing, indeed. But they are not enough, because they are overridden by cmdlet ubiquitous parameters `-Verbose`, `-Debug` if any specified. But these parameters are not accessible from a cmdlet. Do parameters change the local `$DebugPreference`, `$VerbosePreference` implicitely? I doubt that, but I will try to find out.

Comment: “Do ubiquitous parameters change the local `$DebugPreference`, `$VerbosePreference`?” – No, they do not. Well, basically I am coming to a conclusion that in case of expensive verbose or debug output a cmdlet should introduce additional switches or even parameters, kind of `-VerboseLevel <int | string | enum>`. Hmm, perhaps this is not a bad idea, actually.

Comment: Yep, in some scripts I used exactly that. More levels of verbosity to get what I really want. And besides that.. I got rid off the 'VERBOSE:' and 'DEBUG:' prefixes.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
BEGIN {
    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"].IsPresent) {
        $HasDebugFlag = $true
    }

    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Verbose"].IsPresent) {
        $HasVerboseFlag = $true
    }
}
PROCESS {
    if ($HasVerboseFlag) {
        expensive_processing
    }
}
```

Caveat: Tested only on PowerShell 3.

Comment: This is good, indeed. +1. This should work in some cases, actually, many. It will not work if the modes are set not by parameters but via `$VerbosePreference` or `$DebugPreference`. Thus, the `if`-s should also check for these variables. But V3 introduced custom default values. Bound parameters might not help if the modes are enabled via custom defaults.

Comment: And does not work if one cmdlet is called from another.

Answer (score 6):

So not only do we have to take the common parameters -Debug and -Verbose of the cmdlet into account, but also the global $DebugPreference and $VerbosePreference flags and the fact that these common parameters are inherited if a cmdlet is called from another cmdlet.

It can be done without hacking around in the internals.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916709/1242) shows you it can be done with little problems in a PowerShell cmdlet.

```
function f { [cmdletbinding()]Param() 
    $debug = $DebugPreference -ne 'SilentlyContinue'
    $verbose = $VerbosePreference -ne 'SilentlyContinue'
    "f is called"
    "    `$debug = $debug"
    "    `$verbose = $verbose"
}
function g { [cmdletbinding()]Param() 
    "g is called"
    f 
}
f
f -Debug -Verbose
g
g -Debug -Verbose
```

From C# we have to check both these global flags, but also the common parameters. Be sure to inherit from PSCmdlet instead of Cmdlet to get to the GetVariableValue method.

```
bool debug = false;
bool containsDebug = MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("Debug");
if (containsDebug)
    debug = ((SwitchParameter)MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"]).ToBool();
else
    debug = (ActionPreference)GetVariableValue("DebugPreference") != ActionPreference.SilentlyContinue;

bool verbose = false;
bool containsVerbose = MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("Verbose");
if (containsVerbose)
    verbose = ((SwitchParameter)MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Verbose"]).ToBool();
else
    verbose = (ActionPreference)GetVariableValue("VerbosePreference") != ActionPreference.SilentlyContinue;
```