# Write-Verbose ignored in PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm hoping to use the `Write-Verbose` commandlet in scripts and functions.  It works as expected in script (.ps1) files, but not in module (.psm1) files--the commandlet is ignored in modules.

Running the following script:

```
PS> .\scaffold.ps1 -verbose
```

Produces:

```
VERBOSE: starting foo
path: c:\bar.txt
[missing entry here - 'verbose path: c:\bar.txt']
VERBOSE: ending foo
```

scaffold.ps1:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

import-module Common -force

write-verbose "starting foo"

foo "c:\bar.txt"

write-verbose "ending foo"
```

Common.psm1:

```
function foo {

  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
    [string]$path
  )

  write-host "path: $path"
  write-verbose "verbose path: $path"

}
```

I haven't associated a manifest (.psd1) with the module (.psm1) at this point.

Is there a module-specific syntax that I need to use?

** edit **

What I need is a way to determine if the `-verbose` flag has been set on the .PS1 file so I can pass it to the .PSM1 file.

scaffold.ps1:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

import-module Common -force

write-verbose "starting foo"

foo "c:\bar.txt" $verbose_flag # pass verbose setting to module based on what was set on the script itself

write-verbose "ending foo"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer here: [How to properly use the -verbose and -debug parameters in custom cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301562/how-to-properly-use-the-verbose-and-debug-parameters-in-custom-cmdlet)

scaffold.ps1:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

import-module Common -force

write-verbose "starting foo"

foo "c:\bar.txt" -Verbose:($PSBoundParameters['Verbose'] -eq $true)

write-verbose "ending foo"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing; agree that this seems to be the only thing that works; but it smells bad... As such have a feature suggestion.  MS Connect is disabled for PowerShell atm, so have blogged for now: https://developer42.wordpress.com/2017/02/04/powershell-suggestion-simplify-write-verbose-in-modules/

Comment: Update: Logged as an issue on PowerShell's GitHub page: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3106

Answer (score 11):

To get `Write-Verbose` output from a cmdlet in a module, you need to use the `-verbose` common  parameter. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff677563.aspx

Using your code:

```
>import-module R:\Common.psm1
>foo "c:\users"
path: c:\users
>foo "c:\users" -verbose
path: c:\users
VERBOSE: verbose path: c:\users
```

Comment: Is the presence of the -verbose toggle made available as a variable within the .ps1 file itself?  `foo "c:\bar.txt" $verbose` or something similar?

Comment: Not that I can tell from the documentation. Why would you need to test for it? Just use `Write-Verbose` - if `-verbose` is used, it'll produce output, otherwise it'll remain silent.

Comment: `-verbose` will enable the `Write-Verbose` code in the .PS1 file only.  I'm hoping to have a way to pass this setting to .PSM1 without having to explicitly write `-verbose` for each module call in the .PS1 file--hence the idea of a `$verbose` variable.

Comment: I agree, this answer does address the part of the question: "What I need is a way to determine if the -verbose flag has been set on the .PS1 file so I can pass it to the .PSM1 file."

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is that variables in a caller's scope do not get picked up by code in a script module.  When you call ".\scaffold.ps1 -verbose", $VerbosePreference is set to 'Continue' in scaffold.ps1's script scope.  If you call a compiled Cmdlet from that script, it honors that $VerbosePreference value, but when you call Advanced Functions from a script module, they do not.

I've recently written a function that allows you to import the preference variables from the caller, using a combination of $PSCmdlet and $ExecutionContext.SessionState to get at the appropriate variable scopes.  The call to this command, at the beginning of a script module's exported function, looks like this:

```
Get-CallerPreference -Cmdlet $PSCmdlet -SessionState $ExecutionContext.SessionState
```

The Get-CallerPreference function can be downloaded from http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Inherit-Preference-82343b9d

Comment: Great and clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not verbose output is printed, is decided by the global `$VerbosePreference` variable, similar to the `$ErrorActionPreference`. The default of the verbose preference is `SilentlyContinue`.

So besides passing through the verbose value, you should als set this:

```
$VerbosePreference = "continue"
```

You can enable it globally in your session or set it for the function scope.