# Recursive -Verbose in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there an easy way to make the -Verbose switch "passthrough" to other function calls in Powershell?

I know I can probably search $PSBoundParameters for the flag and do an if statement:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Function Invoke-CustomCommandA {
    Write-Verbose "Invoking Custom Command A..."

    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Verbose")) {
        Invoke-CustomCommandB -Verbose
    } else {
        Invoke-CustomCommandB
    }
}

Invoke-CustomCommandA -Verbose
```

It seems rather messy and redundant to do it this way however... Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to use $PSDefaultParameters at the top of your advanced function:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"*:Verbose"=($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')}
```

Then every command you invoke with a `-Verbose` parameter will have it set depending on whether or not you used -Verbose when you invoked your advanced function.

If you have just a few commands the do this:

```
$verbose = [bool]$PSBoundParameters["Verbose"]
Invoke-CustomCommandB -Verbose:$verbose
```

Comment: I would do a $PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.clone() first, otherwise you're probably going to end up setting it for the global scope and not just the function and it's child scopes.

Comment: Why?  `$PSDefaultParamaterValues` obeys the same scoping rules that other variables obey.  If I had done `$global:PSDefaultParameterValues=...` then it would write to the value to the globally scoped `$PSDefaultParameterValues`.

Comment: You're adding a key to a hash table, not creating a new variable.  If that hash table doesn't exist in the function scope it will start looking for it in a parent scope, not create a new one.

Comment: I beg to differ. Assigning to a variable within a scope which has the same name as a global variable will do a "copy-on-write" op - essentially creating a new variable that shadows the global variable.  Try the experiment.  I have.  :-)

Comment: You're right. It does create a new hash table. But you also lose any default parameter settings already set.  If you want to retain those in the function you need to clone the existing $PSDefaultParameterValues in the function, and then add the new entry to that.

Comment: Good point!  FWIW I've heard several module authors suggest a best practice is to reset PSDefaultParameterValues at the module scope to prevent a user's default's from screwing up module operation.  Reminds me of the old C saying "globals are evil".  :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure [you don't want PSBoundParameters, you want PSCmdlet.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767616/1404637)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$vb = $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Verbose')
Invoke-CustomCommandB -Verbose:$vb
```

Comment: It turns out that doesn't work correctly if the user calls the advanced function with `-Verbose:$false`.  Admittedly, that's a bit of a corner case.  :-)

Comment: I have been using the following succesfully even with `-Verbose:$false` :

`If($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters['Verbose'].IsPresent) { 
            $Verbose=$True
        }
        Else {
            $Verbose=$False
        }#EndIf`

Something tells me it can be simplified but I went for the ease of readability in that example.

Comment: Simplified version of my previous post:`$Verbose=[bool]$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters['Verbose'].IsPresent`. This handle the case where Verbose is not present and IsPresent return a $null value.

Answer (score 2):

I began using [KeithHill's $PSDefaultParameterValues technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20393279/1404637) in some powershell modules.  I ran into some pretty surprising behavior which I'm pretty sure resulted from [the effect of scope and $PSDefaultParameterValues being a sort-of global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393040/recursive-verbose-in-powershell/31421267#comment30479339_20393279).  I ended up writing a cmdlet called `Get-CommonParameters` (alias `gcp`) and using splat parameters to achieve explicit and terse cascading of `-Verbose` (and the other common parameters).  Here is an example of how that looks:

```
function f1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    process
    {
        $cp = &(gcp)
        f2 @cp
        # ... some other code ...
        f2 @cp
    }
}
function f2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    process
    {
        Write-Verbose 'This gets output to the Verbose stream.'
    }
}
f1 -Verbose
```

The source for cmdlet `Get-CommonParameters` (alias `gcp`) is in [this github repository](https://github.com/alx9r/a9Foundations/blob/master/Functions/cmdlet.ps1).