# How to propagate -Verbose to module functions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

According to answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301562/how-to-properly-use-the-verbose-and-debug-parameters-in-custom-cmdlet/20830886#20830886) and my own experience, Powershell can take care of propagating -Verbose (and -Debug) automatically, which is very convenient. However this stops working when the functions which I want to propagate verbosity to are in a module. Code used for testing this:

Create a directory called `Mod` somewhere, suppose in c:, and add 2 files:

File `c:\Mod\Functions.ps1`:

```
function Show-VerbosityB { [cmdletbinding()]Param()
  Write-Output "Show-VerbosityB called"
  Write-Verbose "Show-VerbosityB is Verbose"
}
```

File `c:\Mod\Mod.psd1`:

```
@{
ModuleVersion = '1.0.0.0'
NestedModules = @('Functions.ps1')
FunctionsToExport = @('*-*')
}
```

Now crate the main script, say `c:\Foo.ps1`:

```
Import-Module c:\Mod

function Show-VerbosityA { [cmdletbinding()]Param()
  Write-Output "Show-VerbosityA called"
  Write-Verbose "Show-VerbosityA is Verbose"
}

function Show-Verbosity { [cmdletbinding()]Param()
  Write-Output "Show-Verbosity called"
  Write-Verbose "Show-Verbosity is Verbose"
  Write-Output "Testing propagation"
  Show-VerbosityA
  Show-VerbosityB
}

Show-Verbosity -Verbose
```

Results in

```
PS> . C:\Foo.ps1
Show-Verbosity called
VERBOSE: Show-Verbosity is Verbose
Testing propagation
Show-VerbosityA called
VERBOSE: Show-VerbosityA is Verbose
Show-VerbosityB called
```

Why is the Write-Verbose in the module's function skipped, why does propagation not behave like it does for Show-VerbosityA? (If I just dot-source Functions.ps1 instead of importing the module, the line `VERBOSE: Show-VerbosityB is Verbose` is printed). I could make propagation manual by e.g. calling `Show-VerbosityB -Verbose:$PSBoundParameters['Verbose']`. Or are there other, preferrably shorter, ways? It is quite messy if functions behave differently depending on whether they are part of a module or dot-sourced.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the `$VerbosePreference` is not propagated when the module is called. 
I modified your script to explicitly print the value at the same points you are outputting via `Write-Verbose` and `Write-Output`.

[This powershell.org post](https://powershell.org/2014/01/13/getting-your-script-module-functions-to-inherit-preference-variables-from-the-caller/) proposes adding this to the module, which worked like a charm for me:

```
if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Verbose'))
{
    $VerbosePreference = $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('VerbosePreference')
}
```

<sub>One of the comments mentions bug report with link (it doesn't exist or I don't have permissions to view)</sub>

The issue is [discussed in a TechNet post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/26/weekend-scripter-access-powershell-preference-variables/), with [a link to a `Get-CallerPreferance` function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Inherit-Preference-82343b9d) that addresses this issue.

---

**Module:**

```
function Show-VerbosityB { [cmdletbinding()]Param()

    <# uncomment to get verbose preference from caller, when verbose switch not explicitly used.
    if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Verbose'))
    {
        $VerbosePreference = $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('VerbosePreference')
    }
    #>

    Write-Output "`nShow-VerbosityB called"
    Write-output "Global pref: $($global:VerbosePreference)"
    Write-output "Script pref: $($script:VerbosePreference)"
    Write-output "Effect pref: $VerbosePreference"
    Write-Verbose "Show-VerbosityB is Verbose"
}
```

**Caller:**

```
Import-Module C:\Mod

Write-output "On startup: $VerbosePreference"

function Show-VerbosityA { [cmdletbinding()]Param()
  Write-Output "`nShow-VerbosityA called"
  Write-output "Global pref: $($global:VerbosePreference)"
  Write-output "Script pref: $($script:VerbosePreference)"
  Write-output "Effect pref: $VerbosePreference"
  Write-Verbose "Show-VerbosityA is Verbose"
}

function Show-Verbosity { [cmdletbinding()]Param()
  Write-Output "`nShow-Verbosity called"
  Write-output "Global pref: $($global:VerbosePreference)"
  Write-output "Script pref: $($script:VerbosePreference)"
  Write-output "Effect pref: $VerbosePreference"
  Write-Verbose "Show-Verbosity is Verbose"
  Write-Output "`nTesting propagation"
  Show-VerbosityA
  Show-VerbosityB
}

Show-Verbosity -Verbose
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer indeed. Unfortunately not exactly what I was hoping for :] Modifying every function to deal with this is crazy, so if I need all verbosity I'll probably just resort to something like `$global:VerbosePreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Continue`..

Comment: Global variables are ugly. Calling the linked `Get-CallerPreferance` function is a one-liner. For me it's worth it to let my module functions behave like built-in cmdlets and not having to worry at the caller site.

Comment: Weird, this isn't working for me (Get-CallerPreference etc). The $PSCmdlet value is present but as soon as I call across to a function from another psm1 the functions in that other psm1 are seeing $PSCmdlet as null...

Comment: Never mind! My issue was that I wasn't specifying [cmdletbinding()]param on the functions within my other psm1. Adding the cmdletbinding() caused the $PSCmdlet variable to work.

Comment: More technically correct, things like `VerbosePrefreence`, `DebugPreference`, and `WhatIfPreference` may not be properly propagated between functions in different _script_ modules. [Microsoft is aware of this issue and has, for some time, been trying to fix this inconsistent behavior.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/221#issuecomment-592954839)

Answer (score 1):

If you want set from the caller script, try this:

(Get-Module 'ModuleName').SessionState.PSVariable.Set('Global:VerbosePreference', $VerbosePreference )