# PowerShell module function does not inherit WhatIf

Tags: function, powershell, testing, module

*TL;DR: Why do module functions not inherit `-WhatIf` implicitly when called from a script?*

It was my understanding that cmdlets and functions will inherit switches such as `-WhatIf` from a calling script, however I have seen behaviour that demonstrates this is not always the case. I have confirmed that the examples in [How do you support PowerShell's -WhatIf & -Confirm parameters in a Cmdlet that calls other Cmdlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180271) work fine for me, but the problem seems to happen when my script is calling a function that is defined in a module.

In my case I have a script with a function defined locally (i.e. in the PS1) file. This script imports a script module. When I run my main script with the `-WhatIf` switch, the local function inherits the `-WhatIf` state but module functions do NOT exhibit the "WhatIf" behaviour, potentially disastrously.

If I call `Show-WhatIfOutput` with the `-WhatIf` switch set explicitly, it works as expected.

If I move the `Call-ShowWhatIf` function from the script to the module, and use `Call-ShowWhatIf -WhatIf` it works fine. That is, `Show-WhatIfOutput` does have `-WhatIf` set implicitly, but this is not a solution I can use in my real-world case.

Even more simply, if I enable `SupportsShouldProcess` on the main script, the same pattern emerges: the local function will inherit the switch; however, the module functions will not.

**Why does the module function not inherit `-WhatIf` when called from the script?**

---

### Test code

**Test-WhatIf.psm1**

```
function Show-WhatIfOutput {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param(
    )

    Write-Host $MyInvocation.Line.Trim()

    if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("My host","Display WhatIf text")){
        Write-Warning "This is not WhatIf text!"
    }

    Write-Host ("-"*40)
}
```

**Test-WhatIf.ps1**

```
Import-Module C:\Test-WhatIf.psm1 -Force

function Call-ShowWhatIf {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param(
    )

    Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.Line.Trim()) > " -NoNewline
    Show-WhatIfOutput

    Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.Line.Trim()) > " -NoNewline
    Show-WhatIfOutput -WhatIf
}

Write-Host ("-"*40)

Show-WhatIfOutput
Show-WhatIfOutput -WhatIf
Call-ShowWhatIf
Call-ShowWhatIf -WhatIf
```

Save both of these files to (say) `C:\` and run the PS1 script. The output I receive is:

```
----------------------------------------
Show-WhatIfOutput
WARNING: This is not WhatIf text!
----------------------------------------
Show-WhatIfOutput -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Display WhatIf text" on target "My host".
----------------------------------------
Call-ShowWhatIf > Show-WhatIfOutput
WARNING: This is not WhatIf text!
----------------------------------------
Call-ShowWhatIf > Show-WhatIfOutput -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Display WhatIf text" on target "My host".
----------------------------------------
Call-ShowWhatIf -WhatIf > Show-WhatIfOutput
WARNING: This is not WhatIf text!
----------------------------------------
Call-ShowWhatIf -WhatIf > Show-WhatIfOutput -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Display WhatIf text" on target "My host".
----------------------------------------
```

You can see that in the 2nd "block" of output I call the module function directly and get a WhatIf statement.

You can see that in the 5th "block" of output I call the module function from within the local `Call-ShowWhatIf` function, as get the warning to say that WhatIf was not set.

Comment: What PowerShell version is this?

Comment: PowerShell 5.1.15063.483

Answer (score 4):

Caller [Preference Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-5.1) are not propagated from `Call-ShowWhatIf` to `Show-WhatIfOutput`. AFAIK this is a known issue with functions called from a module. In this case, it's the `$WhatIfPreference` that is not being propagated.

Adding this to your `Show-WhatIfOutput` should resolve the issue:

```
if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf'))
{
    $WhatIfPreference= $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('WhatIfPreference')
}
```

It checks if the ***caller*** (`Call-ShowWhatIf`) has `-WhatIf` specified. It does this when `-WhatIf` is not specified in the ***function call*** (`Show-WhatIfOutput`)

[This is a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900568/how-to-propagate-verbose-to-module-functions/44902512) which described the same issue with `-Verbose` not propagating.

<sub>Related links:

[PowerShell.org - Script Modules and Variable Scopes](https://powershell.org/2014/01/20/revisited-script-modules-and-variable-scopes/)

[Scripting Guy - Weekend Scripter: Access PowerShell Preference Variables](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/26/weekend-scripter-access-powershell-preference-variables/)

[TechNet - Import Preference variables from the caller of a Script Module function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Inherit-Preference-82343b9d)</sub>

Comment: I'll read the links ASAP; I'm looking for both an explanation of why this happens and ideas for how to solve or work around the issue. Ideally I don't want to have to add logic to each of my module functions.

Comment: Thanks! More arcana for supporting expected behavior!
I'd recommend adding another check for `Confirm` and `ConfirmPreference` as part of the snippet, given that `SupportsShouldProcess()` is presumed to support and inherit both.