# In a Cmdlet, how can I detect if the Debug flag is set?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell Cmdlet and using [WriteDebug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writedebug%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I want to write an object which requires an extra API call, and I'd rather not make that call when debugging is turned off. How can I detect whether the Debug flag is set or not, so that I can skip this call to WriteDebug entirely?

For example, my WriteDebug call will look something like this:

```
WriteDebug(string.Format("Name : {0}", api.GetName(myobj)));
```

In that example, I want to avoid the call to `api.GetName` unless debugging is turned on.

Comment: Based on [stej's answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2777219/2495), I would guess there is no straightforward way to get the current value of `$DebugPreference` from a cmdlet.

Answer (score 5):

Just checking if the -Debug flag is set can be done with the code below, but it is not enough.

```
bool debug = false;
bool containsDebug = MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("Debug");
if (containsDebug)
    debug = ((SwitchParameter)MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"]).ToBool();
```

PowerShell also allows you to set a global flag called $DebugPreference which the code above does not check. And calling a cmdlet from another cmdlet inherits these common parameters which is not inherited through the Debug flag as the code above checks. The code below will check $DebugPreference and solves those problems.

```
debug = (ActionPreference)GetVariableValue("DebugPreference") != ActionPreference.SilentlyContinue;
```

Unfortunately [in contrary to a cmdlet in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916709/1242) you have to check both. So the final C# code is as below. I have also added the code for the Verbose common parameter as bonus. Be sure to inherit from PSCmdlet instead of Cmdlet to get to the GetVariableValue method.

```
bool debug = false;
bool containsDebug = MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("Debug");
if (containsDebug)
    debug = ((SwitchParameter)MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"]).ToBool();
else
    debug = (ActionPreference)GetVariableValue("DebugPreference") != ActionPreference.SilentlyContinue;

bool verbose = false;
bool containsVerbose = MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("Verbose");
if (containsVerbose)
    verbose = ((SwitchParameter)MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Verbose"]).ToBool();
else
    verbose = (ActionPreference)GetVariableValue("VerbosePreference") != ActionPreference.SilentlyContinue;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$Debug = $psboundparameters.debug.ispresent


if ($Debug){
  Write-Debug(string.Format("Name : {0}", api.GetName(myobj))
  }
```

Comment: +1 -have you a good link that explain this kind of awesome use of  $psboundparameters? thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, no.  I just ran up a test functions and checked to see how the -debug switch showed up in the binding.

Comment: How would I access this from C#? I'm writing a C# class that extends [PSCmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscmdlet(v=vs.85).aspx), not a script cmdlet.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know that.  I suspect it's going to involve something called a "variabletoken", but won't speculate further.

Comment: $psboundparameters usage is discribed in [about_Automatic_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347675.aspx)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the Debug setting is inherited, but its presence in psboundparameters is not inherited.  (Sorry, I don't have anything constructive to contribute.)

Comment: I understood the question to be how to control writing a debug message only if -debug was explicitly specified on this function, not just enabled by inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Experimentation indicates you might want to look at the $DebugPreference variable.  I tried it with advanced functions, but it probably works just as well in a cmdlet.

Try the following sequence of commands:

```
function f { [cmdletbinding()]Param() $DebugPreference }
function g { [cmdletbinding()]Param() f }
f
f -Debug
g
g -Debug
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the Debug flag from C# you should be able to do essentially the same thing as mjolinor suggests:

```
if (this.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("Debug"))
{
    ... do something ...
}
```

However, note that you can specify the debug parameter with a value of false:

```
MyCmdlet -Debug:$false
```

To handle this case, you probably want to add something like this (from within the PSCmdlet):

```
bool debug = MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("Debug") &&
             ((SwitchParameter)MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"]).ToBool();
```

In C# BoundParameters is a dictionary, so you could also use TryGetValue(), but note that the value of a switch (like Debug) is a SwitchParameter not a bool.

for further information see the following:

- PSCmdlet.MyInvocation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.myinvocation(v=vs.85).aspx
- BoundParameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.boundparameters(v=vs.85).aspx
- SwitchParameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.switchparameter(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This does not work if a cmdlet is called from another cmdlet and does not take the $DebugPreference into account.