# Detect -Debug and -Verbose function parameters in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, powershell, vb.net-2010

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Visual Basic, and am creating a custom PowerShell Cmdlet.

How do I detect if either the `-Verbose` or `-Debug` parameters are used?
I have tried `If Debug.IsPresent Then`, but that does not appear to work.

Comment: Do you mean [Environment.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline(v=vs.110).aspx)? You can just parse it and verify presense of certain tokens.

Comment: Out of interest: Why would you want to? WriteDebug and WriteVerbose already take those into account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to examine the parameters that are passed into the cmdlet. Use the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable to determine which parameters were specified.

For more information, see: `Get-Help -Name about_Automatic_Variables;`

Comment: Sorry, I meant from within a VB.NET dll compiled, not script.

Comment: Yeah, I know. You should still be able to check the value of that variable inside of your cmdlet, however. The same principle applies to both script and compiled code.

Comment: This is only half the solution. It does not take $DebugPreference and $VerbosePreference into account and does not work when one cmdlet calls another.

Answer (score 0):

It is not VB.Net, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20827954/1242) is a solution in C# which should translate to VB.Net with ease