# PowerShell VB.NET cmdlet. Change -DEBUG switch

Tags: vb.net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

The trying to prevent the (apparently default) Inquire mode in WriteDebug and this does not work (See earlier post). As I do not yet know
how to detect if -DEBUG is set on the command line I am trying this:

```
(<Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "MyCmdlet", SupportsShouldProcess:=False)> _

Protected Overrides Sub BeginProcessing()          
  setting = SessionState.PSVariable                                    
  dbPref = setting.Get("DebugPreference").Value
  vbPref = setting.Get("VerbosePreference").Value
  WriteObject("VBpref: " & vbPref.ToString)
  WriteObject("DBpref: " & dbPref.ToString)
  setting.Set("VerbosePreference", ActionPreference.Continue)
  setting.Set("DebugPreference", ActionPreference.Continue)
  dbPref = setting.Get("DebugPreference").Value
  vbPref = setting.Get("VerbosePreference").Value
  WriteObject("VBpref: " & vbPref.ToString)
  WriteObject("DBpref: " & dbPref.ToString)
  WriteDebug("TEST")
```

The ouput is as follows:

```
PS> Test-MyCmdlet -d
VBpref: SilentlyContinue
DBpref: SilentlyContinue
VBpref: Continue
DBpref: Continue
DEBUG: TEST

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
```

And this is the output without the -D switch (no Inquire):

```
PS> Test-MyCmdlet
VBpref: SilentlyContinue
DBpref: SilentlyContinue
VBpref: Continue
DBpref: Continue
DEBUG: TEST
```

So why, if the reset above has worked, am I still in Inquire mode? And how can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

```
public PSVariableIntrinsics PSVariable { get; }
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.sessionstate.psvariable%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I'm not developer, but I guess that means that any changes you do to you `settings` will not be applied to the users session, but only in the local copyin you stored in your variable.

As for detecting the debug-setting, you could try something like this which is from an earlier [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9903185/702944):

```
bool debug = MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("Debug") &&
             ((SwitchParameter)MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"]).ToBool();
```

Answer (score 0):

The default of $DebugPreference is not Inquire, but SilentContinue as you can read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx). And your own output proves it.

Properly detecting why WriteDebug knows when to write is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20827954/1242).

The reason WriteDebug still asks questions is because you called your cmdlet with -Debug. I don't see why setting $DebugPreference would change that. I also see no way of changing the -Debug parameter while your cmdlet is executing.

I doubt that really is what you want and if it is I do not understand why. Maybe we can help you better if you explain why you would want to.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to use the -DEBUG switch as a filter, exactly like -VERBOSE, to output certain messages without a user prompt.
I can cheat a bit by adding an (unnecessary) switch parameter, causing this to work:

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to change the semantics of -Debug and -Verbose. I would leave it alone and use WriteVerbose. If you really need more levels of verbose output I would introduce your own extra parameters.